# Source for package SQLServer2012SP4KB4018073x64ENU.exe does not exist in chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

i am trying to install sql server 2012 using chef to a virtual box.. Below is the code that i use but i am getting source does not exist error. Below is the server.rb code that i have..

```
package package_name do
  source 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\SQLServer2012SP4KB4018073x64ENU.exe'# package_url
  checksum package_checksum
  timeout node['sql_server']['server']['installer_timeout']
  installer_type :custom
  options "/q /ConfigurationFile=#{config_file_path} #{passwords_options}"
  action :install
  notifies :request_reboot, 'reboot[sql server install]'
  returns [0, 42, 127, 3010]
```

Error

```
 * template[C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\kitchen\cache\ConfigurationFile.ini] action create (up to date)
 windows_package[SQLServer2012SP4KB4018073x64ENU.exe] action install
 * Source for package SQLServer2012SP4KB4018073x64ENU.exe does not exist
```

Comment: Can you confirm that path exists and there's a file with that exact name? Why are you keeping it in `\Local\Temp`? That's practically the same as keeping it in the recycle bin.

Comment: Yes there is a file in there, i have tried other locations but i recieve the same error

Comment: Path for `template` and `windows_package` are different. Should the package also be in a location accessible for vagrant?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from making the file accessible for `windows_package` resource, one more change can be made.

The name of [windows_package resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/windows_package/) should match the application name displayed in Control Panel. As you are using `SQLServer2012SP4KB4018073x64ENU.exe` as the name, Chef will start installation of the package every time it is run (which is probably not what we want).

For e.g. if I want to install a simple package like WinSCP, which is displayed in Control Panel as `WinSCP <version>`, then I should name my resource with that.

```rb
windows_package 'WinSCP 5.17.7' do
  source 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\WinSCP-5.17.7-Setup.exe'
  installer_type :custom
  options '/silent'
end
```

Now if Chef runs again, it will make this install idempotent.

Comment: I Tried this, but same error "Source for package Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (64-bit) does not exist"

Comment: This is not a solution for `source` issue. Seems you are using vagrant to spin up VM in Virtual Box and deploy with Chef?

Comment: Yes i am trying spin up VM and install sql through chef ... using vagrant. The default cookbook source is using a url that downloads from microsoft . But i want to change it to my own location , but when changing this url to local drive ,i am getting the above error.